# SparkSQL cannot find existing rows in a Hive table that Trino(Presto) does

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, presto, trino

We are using Trino(Presto) and SparkSQL for querying Hive tables on s3 but they give different results with the same query and on the same tables. We found the main problem. There are existing rows in a problematic Hive table which can be found with a simple where filter on a specific column with Trino but cannot be found with SparkSQL. The sql statements are the same in both.

On the other hand, SparkSQL can find these rows in the source table of that problematic table, filtering on the same column.

**Create sql statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE problematic_hive_table AS SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM source_table
```

**The select sql that can be used to find missing rows in Trino but not in SparkSQL**

```
SELECT * FROM problematic_hive_table WHERE c1='missing_rows_value_in_column'
```

**And this is the select query which can find these missing rows in SparkSQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE c1='missing_rows_value_in_column'
```

We execute the CTAS in Trino(Presto). If we are using `...WHERE trim(c1) = 'missing_key''` then spark can also find the missing rows but the fields do not contain trailing spaces (the length of these fields are the same in the source table as in the problematic table). In the source table spark can find these missing rows without trim.

Comment: Do you execute your CTAS in Presto? IIRC Spark requires to use USING <datasource_type> in it. Also, could you try `...WHERE trim(c1) = 'missing_key'` to eliminate the possibility of trailing spaces in the new table?

Comment: Yes, i execute the CTAS in Trino(Presto). If we are using `...WHERE trim(c1) = 'missing_key''` then spark can also find the missing rows but the fields do not contain trailing spaces (the length of these fields are the same in the source table as in the problematic table). In the source table spark can find these missing rows without trim.